# What is wrong with my MySQL syntax in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table named 'Component' I am trying to query the items that have a 'LifecycleStatus' of Active with a specific 'EndOfLifeDate'.

Here is the describe of my table.

```
mysql> describe component;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| componentID     | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| vendorName      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Family          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cdescription    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CategoryType    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| endOfSaleDate   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| endOfLifeDate   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LifeCycleStatus | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here is my query with the error.

```
mysql> SELECT C.vendorName
    -> FROM Component C
    -> GROUP BY C.LifecycleStatus
    -> HAVING EndOfLifeDate = '4/30/2024' ;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'EndOfLifeDate' in 'having clause'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tried with lowercase e in the beginning as the table description shows?

Comment: What could you possibly be trying to do?  The query has inconsistent column usage in the `SELECT`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING`.  And the data model is malformed too, using strings instead of `date`.

Comment: What is the point of GROUP BY if you don't do any aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query :

```
mysql> SELECT C.vendorName
    -> FROM Component C
    -> GROUP BY C.LifecycleStatus
    -> HAVING EndOfLifeDate = '4/30/2024' ;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'EndOfLifeDate' in 'having clause'
```

HAVING works on columns that you have selected or columns on which you have applied group by.

You can try this ,

```
mysql> SELECT C.vendorName , C.EndOfLifeDate
    -> FROM Component C
    -> GROUP BY C.LifecycleStatus
    -> HAVING C.EndOfLifeDate = '4/30/2024' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `WHERE`, not `HAVING`:

```
SELECT C.vendorName
FROM Component C
WHERE endOfLifeDate = '4/30/2024'
GROUP BY C.vendorName;
```

`HAVING` is evaluated *after* the `GROUP BY`, so it should only use `GROUP BY` keys and expressions with aggregation functions.

Note:  This also fixes the `GROUP BY` so it matches the `SELECT` columns.

Then, fix your data model.  You should not be storing dates as strings.  They should be stored as `date`.  That is what the data type is for.